# Unable to find my puppet module

Tags: puppet

I'm just trying to get my head around puppet, and decided to get stuck in using a really simple module.

I'm using puppet version **3.6.2**

I've used the command

```
puppet module generate tsv-tsvversion
```

It created the following module stub

```
/etc/puppet/modules/
└── tsv-tsvversion
    ├── manifests
    │   └── init.pp
    ├── metadata.json
    ├── Rakefile
    ├── README.md
    ├── spec
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   └── init_spec.rb
    │   └── spec_helper.rb
    └── tests
        └── init.pp
```

The init.pp in manifests looks like

```
class tsvversion {
        group {'test':
                   ensure => present,
              }

        user { 'matt':
                        ensure           => 'present',
                        comment          => 'Matt',
                        gid              => 'test',
                        home             => '/home/matt',
                        password         => '',
                        password_max_age => '-1',
                        password_min_age => '-1',
                        shell            => '/bin/bash',
                        uid              => '2002',
                        managehome       => 'true',
             }
}
```

My modules seem to be on the modulepath

```
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

The manifests/site.pp looks like

```
node default {

Package {  allow_virtual => false, }

    include 'tsvversion'
}
```

When I run this on the puppet master

```
puppet agent --test --verbose
```

it fails with

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class tsvversion for puppet.tsvtest on node puppet.tsvtest
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Before posting, i've checked to make sure i'm using lowercase, and no silly characters.

I'm struggling to understand why it fails.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: // , Did you get `puppet module build /etc/puppet/modules/tsv-tsvversion` to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root directory of your module must not be named `tsv-tsvversion`. The author prefix is only intended for metadata that controls behavior on the Forge, and for downloading using `puppet module install`.

This may not be through any fault of your's, but rather a shortcoming of the `puppet module generate` subcommand. (This might even be a bug.)

Try and rename or link your module to `/etc/puppet/modules/tsvversion`. Your practices look sound otherwise.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I renamed the module from tsv-tsvversion to tsvversion and it works a treat.